# How to get contents of HTML `object`?

Tags: javascript, html, object

**Goal**

I want to put a normal tag in my HTML page to grab text from file from a remote file from my own server. Then, javascript will manipulate the text, and display it on the webpage. So JS must be able to grab the contents of the remote file.

The remote file is called "records.html". It's not a complete webpage, just a fragment. It *isn't* json data.

I prefer a pure HTML solution for pulling the data into the page, if possible.

*The remote file is on the same domain as the parent page. It's my html, my JS, my data.*

**Things i've tried:**

**object with text/html type**

HTML:

`<object id="records" type="text/html" data="records.html" ></object>`

JS:

```
window.onload = function getRecords() {
    const obj = document.querySelector("#records");
    console.log(obj.contentDocument.documentElement.innerText)
};
```

It fails. I can see the external contents in the browser dev tools, but

- the output is blank.
- The external HTML file doesn't contain `<html>`, `#document`, or `<body>` tags, but the loaded object content has all those tags. It would be cool to prevent the extra tags, but not critical.
  [image: dev tools]
- In case it's a race condition, I've read `<object>` tags don't support an onload event, so i can't get it's contents with a load event.

**object with application/json type**

This actually works. However, my remote data isn't json. So to use this method, it requires putting non-json data into a file with a .json extension. That seems like very bad form.

```
<object id="records" type="application/json" data="package.json"></object>
<script>
document.getElementById('records').addEventListener('load', function () {
  console.log(this.contentDocument.documentElement.innerText)
})
</script>
```

**link**

`<link type="text/html" href="records.html">`

Doesn't work. I've read this method is deprecated.

**iframe**

I tried with iFrame but it failed. I may have done it wrong.

**XMLHttpRequest + Filesystem API**

I believe this has been superceded by JS `fetch`.

**fetch**

I haven't had any success wrapping a function around fetch. It's returning a Promise{}, instead of data.

```
async function fetchText(sURL) {
    let response = await fetch(sURL);
    let data = await response.text();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason for using `<object>` instead of an `<iframe>`?

Comment: as mentioned in my question, i'm open to using iframe, embed, etc

Comment: @SuperStormer i tried iframe with no luck

Comment: iframe is used to include a complete html document visually (but not programmatically, mostly) into a host html document. What I think you're trying to do is an html include, where a chunk of html from another file is inserted into this one. Do I have the idea of what you're after?

Comment: @Mr.Dave Exactly. But JS needs access to the content. I've read this method is deprecated `<link type="text/html" href="records.html">`

Comment: @Mr.Dave i'm not displaying the imported fragment as-is. It won't be displayed in its raw form. JS will manipulate it, and display it elsewhere on the page. I'm trying to import raw data, for further handling by JS before display.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but my guess is because a more common way of doing this would be to use a CMS, or the features of whatever server-side language or framework you're using. There are risks and challenges to doing this in javascript, so it may be that they are discouraging this path.

Comment: @johnywhy I'm still not the downvoter, so I can only speculate. The risks aren't... things aren't separate like that. If you're only including data that you're sanitizing yourself in advance, it's probably fine. Inserting any data that you gather from an outside internet source is going to put you at risk for cross-site scripting and other attacks.

Comment: @Mr.Dave I understand you're not the downvoter. I'm not using any outside source. As my question says, it's coming from the same domain as my webpage. Can it be done with an iFrame? Many thankx.

Answer (score 1):

`contentDocument`

For example, this is working for me:

```html
<body>
<object id="records" type="application/json" data="package.json"></object>
<script>
document.getElementById('records').addEventListener('load', function () {
  console.log(this.contentDocument.documentElement.innerText)
})
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Using `contentDocument` or `contentDocument,.children`  gives things like *HTMLDocument {location: Location}, location: Location, get location: ƒ get location(), set location: ƒ set location(), __proto__: HTMLDocument,* etc. Drilling down, i cannot find the actual contents of the external page. There are a ton of nodes, but all seems like some sort of metadata. What node should i be looking for?

Comment: @johnywhy Do you have the link? If it's not public, try `$0.contentDocument.documentElement.children`  and from some child, e.g. `children[3].innerText` or so

Comment: What's $0? Like this? `const txt = obj.$0.contentDocument.documentElement.children` ? Here's a link. https://bayviewboom.org/readme.txt

Comment: @johnywhy sorry, by `$0` I meant the reference to your object. Do you have the link with the <object> tag? instead of the actual content link

Comment: children appears to give a bunch of metadata of some sort. innerText is blank.

Comment: `obj.contentDocument.documentElement.innerText`

Comment: `obj.contentDocument.documentElement.innerText` gives "Cannot read properties of of null (reading 'documentElement'). Any more guesses?

Comment: Here's the object with link: `<object id="records" type="text/html" data="https://bayviewboom.org/readme.txt" ></object>`

Comment: In the console of the page, type: `document.querySelector("#records").contentDocument.documentElement.innerText` I want to see if it's a loading race

Comment: document object is giving null in console. That's why i tried to find an onload event for the object, but apparently doesn't support it.

Comment: You can attach a load listener to a loaded element all day long, it will never fire because the element was loaded before the listener existed. an object element doesn't cause the browser to load the json that way.

Comment: @Mr.Dave It works. I tested it.

Comment: Your code works for me, but not with `type="text/html"`

Comment: Your code works if i put my *non-json* data inside the *.json* file. But that seems like a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

If I were doing it, I'd reach for fetch()

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>my neat page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="target"></div>
</body>
<script>
const output = document.getElementById("target");
fetch("./myResource.html")
.then((response)=>response.text())
.then((text)=>{/* This is where you manipulate the text response */})
.then((manipulatedText)=>{output.innerHtml=manipulatedText});
</script>
</html>
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: i came across fetch, but was hoping for a pure HTML method. But ATM seems the only viable option. I like the simplicity of `object`, but my remote file isn't json.

Comment: i also came acrost XMLHttpRequest + Filesystem API, but that seems every more complicated.

Comment: You're making me learn about `then` :)

Comment: i'm trying to make a JS fetch function with simply returns the contents of the external file, but i'm just getting `Promise{}` return. Do i need to loop until i get the data?

Comment: i added my failing `fetch` to my question above.

Comment: i'm parsing the data and distributing bits of it across many elements, so i wouldn't put all that processing inside a `then`.

Comment: @johnywhy you could extract that logic into a separate function and just call that within your .then()

Comment: True! Tho i'm inclined to use a higher level fx `getData(), processData(), writeData()`. For now, the problem is the getData fx. I can't find a way to wrap the fetch and get the data out. I'm just getting a Promise.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74829096/how-to-wrap-js-fetch-inside-a-function-to-return-remote-text